# How to persist user auth with firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I would like to simply persist user auth with Firebase after refreshing I've tried i few solutions I've found but none of them seem to work, I think I'm missing some concepts.

I follow the Firebase documentation and tried to use the following code:

```
const auth = getAuth();
setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
  .then(() => {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

here is the AuthContext code:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  setPersistence,
  browserSessionPersistence,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase";

const AuthContext = createContext({
  user: "",
  errors: "",
  createUser: () => {},
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {},
});

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const createUser = (email, password) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  };

  const login = (email, password) => {
    setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence).then(() => {
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const value = { createUser, login, user: user };
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export default AuthContext;
```

I created and protected a route page to check if the user is logged in.

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../../store/AuthContext";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { user } = context;

  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to="/auth"></Navigate>;
  }
  return <Outlet />;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to persist user auth with Firebase?

The response to this question exists right inside the official documentation regarding [Authentication State Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence):

> You can specify how the Authentication state persists when using the Firebase JS SDK. This includes the ability to specify whether a signed-in user should be indefinitely persisted until explicit sign-out, cleared when the window is closed, or cleared on page reload.

> For a web application, the default behavior is to persist a user's session even after the user closes the browser. This is convenient as the user is not required to continuously sign in every time the web page is visited on the same device. This could require the user having to re-enter their password, send an SMS verification, etc, which could add a lot of friction to the user experience.

Comment: Hey Joao. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?